# NgStyle not being applied to html

Tags: html, css, angular, calc, ng-style

I have this ngStyle below that works like this

```
[ngStyle]="{'height': true ? '100vh' : null }"
```

but doesn't work (get applied) when I use a calc like this

```
[ngStyle]="{'height': true ? 'calc(100vh-100px)' : null }"
```

Can anyone tell me why?

Answer (score 2):

All you need it space before and after `-`. like this -

`[ngStyle]="{'height': true ? 'calc(100vh - 100px)' : null }"`

Comment: thanks for the help! it worked. Is there any shorter syntax where I can remove the null? and obviously replace true with a condition

Comment: If you want to apply multiple conditional styles then you can make object and pass it and appy condition in `component.ts` for ex. - `<some-element [ngStyle]="objExp">...</some-element>` or something like `<some-element [ngStyle]="getStyleObj()">...</some-element>`